# Could not load JDBC driver class in spring

Tags: spring, jdbc

I am using spring framework to access data from database.When I run the main class ,I get a error saying `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerD??river]`.I have added sqljdbc4-2 jar file. App.java is my main class.I have also attached my Spring XML files.Request your help in sorting this issue

```
package org.test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class App 
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
 {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
     System.out.println("inside test");
    CustomerDAO customerDAO = (CustomerDAO) context.getBean("customerDAO");
    Customer customer = new Customer(1, "mkyong",28);
    customerDAO.insert(customer);

    Customer customer1 = customerDAO.findByCustomerId(1);
    System.out.println(customer1);

 }
}
```

spring-Datasource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerD‌​river"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=JAVADB"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value="dbadmin@234"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

spring-Module.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<import resource="Spring-Datasource.xml" />
<import resource="Spring-Customer.xml" />
</beans>
```

Spring-Customer.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="customerDAO" class="org.test.JdbcCustomerDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: it Looks like there are not printable character in your file thats why the question marks ar in the error message: `SQLServerD??river`

Comment: how did you added the sqljdbc jar? it's not in your project's classpath

Comment: @dimitrisli : I am using eclipse IDE.So,project->properties->java build path ->add external jars.

Comment: @jens : Previously I have copy pasted.It is because of that.Now I have typed the code still the same error without that not printable character.

Comment: can you Show your pom file, where you added the SQL...jar?

Comment: do you see the lib in the Eclipse  "Project Exloprer" under the "Referenced Libraries?". If yes, can you expand and see whether the class you are referring to exists?

Comment: @dimitrisli: Yes I can see the jar file .And I can also see SQLServerDriver.class inside the package

Comment: @Jens I am not using pom.xml. I am adding library using properties in project.I can see the jar in referenced libraries.

Comment: And you see it in your classpath? I recommand to use maven with spring projects

Comment: @jens I am able to see that.